# react-native bundling failed: Error: Cannot find module /metro-react-native-babel-transformer/src/index.js

Tags: react-native

I've tried to upgrade `react-native` version from `0.59.8` to `0.60.5` using `rn-diff-purge` https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.8&to=0.60.5

Then I got

> error: bundling failed: Error: Cannot find module '/myapp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/node_modules/metro-react-native-babel-transformer/src/index.js

when running `react-native run-ios`

How to fix this bundling issues?

Comment: Did you pod install??

Comment: Yes, I did pod install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding/researching the solution for days.
Finally, I've found the solution and fixed by doing this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25585#issuecomment-518357303